# Email claims not populated with custom policies in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have Azure B2C with custom policies with Local Login and Microsoft Account login enabled. I have started with the starter pack and made some modifications to add my custom logic for validate and add additional claims as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw).

Everything works fine with Microsoft Account. But I am facing issues with Local Account Sign in.

1. email claim is only populated when the user signup but not on sign-in. In case of sign-in the email is part of "signInNames.emailAddress" claim. I tried making changes as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47145452/return-emails-on-custom-policies) and [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/issues/24). I would like the email to be populate in email claim as my API uses this claim.
2. <strike>Additional calims returned from my REST API are not added to token only for Local Login. They are added for Microsoft Account.</strike>

thank you.

Update: For point 2, its a problem with my policy file and is now fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a simple method to return `email` claim.

Just replace `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />` with `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />` in your `SignUporSignIn.xml` file.

You need to sign up new local user and then sign in to test it. You will see the `email` claim.

In fact, this solution has been provided by @Wayne Yang in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47145452/return-emails-on-custom-policies) you shared.

Comment: I tried that and is not working. email is only populated for local login but not for social providers like Microsoft.

Comment: @user1868744 Try to add both `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />` and `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />`.

Comment: ha strange.. I tried this before and didn't work.. may be some issue with my policy. It works now.. thank you. Do you know why the email is not persisted as email?

Comment: @user1868744 It depends on how the claim returns. For local account, you need get the email from `"signInNames": [ 
    {
        "type": "emailAddress",
        "value": "*@*.com"
    }
]`

Comment: is this working with when using "Sign in with Apple"?