# Return e-mail address - Custom Policies Azure B2C AD (Business Accounts)

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using custom policies in order o integrate Azure B2C AD. I need to be able to use single sign on to Microsoft Business Accounts. I was able to make it work, nevertheless, it doesn't return the emails clain my tokens.

Here is what I did:

1. Downloaded the Start Pack “SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa”
2. I made the changes to the related files based in the articles
   below(step 3 and 4)
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-commonaad-custom
4. [Return emails on custom policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47145452/return-emails-on-custom-policies)

Any idea why it is not working? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the "emails" claim is being returned by a custom OutputClaimsTransformation, the configuration of which isn't available in the samples.

You need to get the email claims dynamically created.

Please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778129/azure-ad-b2c-emails-claim-in-custom-policy) which provides a workaround to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You must map to the **email** claim that is used by Azure AD B2C from the **upn** claim that is issued by Azure AD (which, by convention, should map to the email address for the work account) as follows:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>commonaad</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Common AAD</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Common-AAD">
      <DisplayName>Multi-Tenant AAD</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      ...
      <OutputClaims>
        ...
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
      </OutputClaims>
      ...
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

[The **AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId** technical profile](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/a5350879ec228d11a53bdffd5bedbb1d21af96fb/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L626) adds this **email** claim to the **otherMails** claim by invoking [the **CreateOtherMailsFromEmail** claims transformation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/a5350879ec228d11a53bdffd5bedbb1d21af96fb/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L326) and then saves **otherMails** claim to the user object.